# How to display images and text using JSF?

Tags: jquery, jsf, autocomplete

I have a requirement something like below:

[image: Something like IMDB].

I was able to do it using JQuery Autocomplete/TypeAhead but now i have to use JSF only. I want the format only. Like an h:graphicimage having rowspan and the title to its right and its details below. I tried using JSF PanelGrid for acheiving the format but to no avail. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I said i know it using JQuery. That code i cant post because it is of no use. I need to do it using JSF. i said i have tried panelgrid. Downvoter please underestand !

Answer (score 0):

There are no ready JSF components with features you want. 
So you have three ways:

1. Link a custom JSF library with component you want
2. Write your own JSF component;
3. Use normal html and add your own CSS.

As for me, 3rd way is simplest.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No i dont want the component. I have asked only for the format. how do i display the image and texts. Please forget i have some component